# Run unit tests with Karma on specific browser versions

Tags: javascript, windows, unit-testing, karma-runner

For reference, I'm running on Windows 8.1.  I'm using Karma to run my unit tests, and I'd like to have them run on multiple versions of a browser.  The Karma documentation for browsers says it's possible to use a script to define custom browsers (http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/browsers.html).  I also came across a GitHub issue that suggested using a script to explicitly run specific browser versions.  I've tried this, using some info I found in [this thread](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/796) and installing the karma-script-launcher plugin.  My script is, I believe, identical to the previously linked issue:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" "%1"
```

I'm seeing, however, the same issue; my URL simply has "?id" rather than "?id=1234".

First, is this a viable way to accomplish my goal, or is there another, perhaps more straightforward, way of testing on multiple browser versions?

Second, assuming this is the ideal solution, where am I going wrong with my batch file?

Answer (score 0):

you can run the test on all browsers installed on the machine using detect browser feature..  more detail:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-detect-browsers 
https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-iebrowsers-launcher